# Android Q: Permissions maintaining state after uninstall

Tags: android, android-10.0

I am having an app which is targeting android 27 API. I am testing this app from playstore on device Android Q which work managed device.
`Steps i followed on device Android Q having build build 6`-

1. Installed app and allowed all the permissions(additional permission also which are custom permissions).
2. Uninstalled app from device.
3. Installed again app from playstore and found that app is asking custom permission only instead no permission.

Is it the expected behavior? Anyone know how this is?

Comment: According to [Android's official site](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/permissions), there doesn't seem to be any changes like the ones you mentioned.

Comment: @BugsHappen Yes, but this link doesn't have any info related to work managed device.

Comment: The answer by Rahul is correct.  You can clear the stored information manually by going to Settings, Apps, Storage, ClearData.

What bothers me most about this is that the app cannot control just parts of it, the Google backup is all or nothing and the default is Enabled.

Answer (score 2):

This is something called [Auto Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup).

**Files that are backed up**

> By default, Auto Backup includes files in most of the directories that
>   are assigned to your app by the system:
>
> 1. Shared preferences files.
> 2. Files saved to your app's internal storage, accessed by getFilesDir() or getDir(String, int).
> 3. Files in the
>      directory returned by getDatabasePath(String), which also includes
>      files created with the SQLiteOpenHelper class.
> 4. Files on external
>      storage in the directory returned by getExternalFilesDir(String).
>
> Auto Backup excludes files in directories returned by getCacheDir(),
>   getCodeCacheDir(), or getNoBackupFilesDir(). The files saved in these
>   locations are only needed temporarily, or are intentionally excluded
>   from backup operations.

You can manage it by `AndroidManifest.xml`. See [android:allowBackup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup)

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application android:allowBackup="true" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT**

```
android:fullBackupContent="false"
android:fullBackupOnly="false"
```

There are 2 more rules available to set.

**EDIT 2**

I just found more useful information at the android official website. see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup#settings_data)

> Note: Any permissions a user grants to your app are automatically
>   backed up and restored by the system on devices running Android 7.0
>   (API 24) or newer. However, if a user uninstalls your app, then the
>   system clears any granted permission and the user must grant them
>   again.

My best guess is there should be some difference(like 24hours) until the user settings/permissions will be deleted from the system device/cloud.

Hopes this will answer your query in some way.

Comment: This issue is with Android Q and work managed device. It is not exists on Below Q(p or below).

Comment: @Manmohan just set `android:allowBackup` to **false** and give it a test. Let me know if you still faced the same issue

Comment: @Manmohan give it a test on multiple devices. Are you using MI phone?

Comment: I am testing on Android 10 Which is not available on most os. I am testing it on Google pixel.

Comment: @Manmohan I have modified my answer a bit

Comment: Before setting this, Why this is applicable on Android Q with work managed device only? Any clue?

Comment: @Manmohan Can't tell you about the work managed devices but in the Android Q they have released many major changes like `scoped storage` also Adaptive battery changes, maybe it is just another smart move made by Google developers to enhance user experience. Because a normal user would be happy to see the settings he/she last applied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199066/discussion-between-manmohan-and-rahul-khurana).

Comment: The issue with different behaviour on the emulator is related to Play Service which is not available on all Emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding whether this is an expected behavior in Android Q:
This issue does not reproduce on Android Q emulator. I guess it counts as a baseline.

**More technical details**:

Runtime permissions logic in Android is mostly located in `PackageManagerService` (mostly book keeping for each package) and `ActivityManagerService` (mostly request runtime permission logic)

When package gets deleted, the data cleanup method [removePackageDataLIF](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#18840)
gets called. It is responsible for cleaning up everything including the app permissions. This logic hasn't changed Android Q.

The permissions info is stored in system data directory, not the application's so the app data backup doesn't affect it either.

**But the question remains**: How could this happen?

*One of the possible explanations* could be the flag `PackageManager.DELETE_KEEP_DATA`

You can easily delete package while keeping its data directory after uninstall:

`$ adb shell cmd package uninstall -k your.app.id`

(-k is for keep data)

Now to check whether the permissions are kept in place along with the data directory:

`$ adb root && adb shell cat /data/system/users/0/runtime-permissions.xml | grep your.app.id -A 10`

(this command requires a debuggable phone firmware build)

Looking at the source of [removePackageDataLIF](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#18840) and trying it on my Pixel with debuggable firmware the application permission is kept intact if you kept its data.

---

*Another explanation*

`PackageManagerService` has an another interesting method [setKeepUninstalledPackages](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#24376) Which basically forces android to keep all the data for specified apps even if they were uninstalled.

As you said the device is work managed. Usually management is done with `DevicePolicyManager`. One of the available policies is [setKeepUninstalledPackages](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setKeepUninstalledPackages(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)), which calls the mentioned above `PackageManagerService` method.

Please check your Device admin app code to verify.

Comment: Issue will reproduce only for additional permision(custom permission) and work managed device. Admin app is keeping all permission till Android p. But with Q asking for additional permission.

Comment: Let me clarify first. So you have two apps: one declaring a custom permission and one requesting it. On android P device that permission was granted without being shown in system permissions dialog. On android Q work managed device you see that permission in the dialog. And your question is why is that happening. Right?

Comment: Yes. correct. I want to know the reason behind this

Comment: Can you at least give me more info about this permisson? At least its protection level? It if is not your app, you can do it by calling `adb shell dumpsys package packagename`

Comment: These permissions are for reading data from other app which is admin app also(uri 
provided from custom app which requires those permissions).

Comment: What is the `protectionLevel` of your custom permission?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199019/discussion-between-amaksoft-and-manmohan).

Comment: ... likely it's signature.